# How to access list items in JList from XML file?

Tags: java, swing, xml-parsing

I want to access list items from XML file. Number of List items are not fixed. How can I do that using Java coding?

**This is my code:**

```
 public void xmlfile(){

     File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\ranig\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\FRAME\\abc.xml");
        if (inputFile.exists()) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
             nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        System.out.println("item id : " + eElement.getAttribute("id"));
        System.out.println("a1 : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("a1").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("command : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("command").item(0).getTextContent());
```

Comment: Use Google Luke. There are very many examples how to use JList and how parse XML file. You only need to bring it together.

Comment: can u send me the link @SergiyMedvynskyy

Comment: http://www.google.com/

Comment: Oh I didn't know this link google.com @AndrewThompson. Thank You so much to tell me this link.

Comment: I am telling about the link of related to answer of this question. I have tried but I am not getting the output

Comment: [How to use JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), [How to read XML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)

Comment: *"I am telling about the link of related to answer of this question"* As @SergiyMedvynskyy is trying to tell you, it is not **one** problem for which you'll find **one** page that spoon feeds the code to you. Now off you go and do some research on *each part* of the problem. Then narrow down future questions so that you can either remove Swing from the question, or start with the XML part already working.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, Actually I have tried my level best but my problem is not solved. I don't have to find out the actual solution of my problem. I thought this site is the best site because I got solutions of many problems. But now I think many people in this site are not supported to new users. even these people are going to disappointed me instead of support. My experience is very bad during this question. These people are not trying to understand my question.

Comment: *"..instead of support.."* This is a technical Q&A Site. If you want 'support', go to FaceBook or other social media sites. Down vote fully earned.

Comment: I know this is a technical Q&A Site . My question is also a technical question. But u don't try to understand my question sincerely @AndrewThompson

Comment: I got solution of this problem